# How do I define a "remote variable" for use with Oculus Remote Monitor?

Tags: testing, oculus, oculusgo

Oculus provides a nifty test/profiling tool called Oculus Remote Monitor.  The [docs](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/1.7/concepts/mobile-remote-monitor/) say:

> Applications may expose user-adjustable parameters and variables in
>   their code. Nearly any constant in your code may be turned into a knob
>   that can be updated in real-time during a play test.

But nowhere can I find any documentation on *how* you actually expose such a parameter/variable.  How do we do this?